# Playing short wav files in Google Home

Tags: dialogflow-es, ssml, actions-on-google, google-home

I would like to play a short sound for a more amusing output. If I understand the documentation correctly it should be possible with a reply in api.ai of something like this SSML:

```
<speak>Okay here we go: <audio src="http://example.com/boing.wav">boing</audio>. You are welcome!</speak>
```

Just for reference SSML means [Speech Synthesis Markup Language](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml).

The [web simulator](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/web-simulator) don't play this sound instead all tags seems to be stripped out. Is that not supported yet or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Just came here to ask this same question.. Add me on skype if you have it: 'dreamache'

Comment: @GarySimon I got some answers. We need to use https!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The src URL must also be an https URL (Google Cloud Storage can host your audio files on an https URL).

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your source, there are a few possible reasons:

- The audio file must be served publicly via HTTPS, not HTTP. See the description for `<audio>` on https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml
- The audio file should be in a correct format (see https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml again).
- If you're returning it via the webhook response, you need to make sure you set the `data.google.is_ssml` property in the JSON to true in https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/webhook-format#response

I have the following for my node.js server which works (well, except for the URL):

```js
  var msg = `
  <speak>
    Tone one
    <audio src="https://examaple.com/wav/Dtmf-1.wav"></audio>
    Tone two
    <audio src="https://example.com/wav16/Dtmf-2.wav"></audio>
    Foghorn
    <audio src="https://example.com/mp3/foghorn.mp3"></audio>
    Done
  </speak>
  `;

  var reply = {
    speech: msg,
    data:{
      google:{
        "expect_user_response": true,
        "is_ssml": true
      }
    }
  };

  res.send( reply );
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is what I have for the code. It is in the Text responds field one my intent.

```
 <speak> One second <break time="3s"/> OK, I have used the best quantum processing algorithms known to computer science! Your silly name is $color $number. I hope you like it. <audio src="https://www.partnersinrhyme.com/files/sounds1/WAV/sports/baseball/Ball_Hit_Cheer.wav"></audio> </speak>
```

It does not work in the testing area of the api(dot)ai field, but does work when I turn on the integration and try it at the Google simiulator. here: https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/web-simulator

Comment: Thank you that you took the time to answer. The https was the detail I have missed.